# How to auto fill form fields using info from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of 5 elements like;

`"apple","grape","peach","strawberry","lemon"`

I have a table like;

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr><td class="fruit"><input type="text" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="fruit"><input type="text" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="fruit"><input type="text" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="fruit"><input type="text" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="fruit"><input type="text" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to auto fill each text field with corresponding fruit name from array. The index of array elements and the index of their corresponding input fields are same. Is there any way to do this **without** using `for` or `while` loop, using a variable as index?

Comment: Why is there a limitation?

Comment: in any case, there is no way to do it without a loop. unless you know.. you just write it out individually for each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `.val()` and `.index()`

```
var arr = ["apple","grape","peach","strawberry","lemon"];
$('.fruit input').val(function(){
    return arr[$('.fruit input').index(this)];
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KmvX5/)

Comment: i would say that's cheating since internally jQuery uses a loop to iterate